# How to format number in acumatica report designer

Tags: acumatica

I got some issue about format number, I want to remove 000.00 to 000 and for example 150000 become 150,000

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Acumatica report designer supports Microsoft .Net format syntax.

To use it, select a field in the report designer and assign it a Microsoft .Net format string:
[image: Acumatica report format string]
To remove decimal you can use this format string:

```
='#.'
```

To remove decimal and use a comma as a thousand separator:

```
='###,###,###,###,###,###.'
```

More information about the Microsoft .Net formatting syntax for numeric types is available here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings