# Report - Format of a Numeric Field

Tags: acumatica

Report - Format of a Numeric Field needs to be specified in the Format Property but what if there is no Amount Field format exists in table ! How can I show a calculated amount (Sum or Max) with two decimal places ?? Any Ideas ?

Comment: Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413129/how-to-format-number-in-acumatica-report-designer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this format in the corresponding field

```
#,##0.00
```